# Troubleshooting an error: The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because the item height must be less than the height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a ViewController that at the top, holds a UIView with a UITextView.  Constrained to the bottom of the UIView is a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally.

The UITextView resizes based on user typing in additional lines of text but I am getting an error because of some sizing issue between the collectionView and the collectionViewFlowLayout but I can't for the life of me work it out.

The code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let containerView = UIView()
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupKeyboardObservers()
        setupTopTextView()
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    
    func setupTopTextView() {
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])

        let textView = UITextView()
        containerView.addSubview(textView)
        textView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        
        textView.text = "This is a test"
        
    }
    
    
    
    func setupCollectionView() {
                    
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
    
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(BasicCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: BasicCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

    }
  
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        4
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BasicCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BasicCollectionViewCell
                    
        let backgroundColorOptions = [UIColor.systemGreen, .systemPurple, .brown, .systemRed]
        cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColorOptions[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

The BasicCollectionViewCell literally has nothing yet as I am just trying to get these elements working and resizing correctly:

```
class BasicCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
            
        static let reuseIdentifier = "BASIC_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL"
        
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    

}
```

The error I get happens when the UITextView increases or decreases in height:

```
2020-07-02 16:34:06.922059+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-07-02 16:34:06.922175+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2020-07-02 16:34:06.922554+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ffbfc016350>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7ffbf9844600; frame = (0 94; 414 802); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000017c9200>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000019d2ba0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1656, 816}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 34, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ffbfc016350>; dataSource: <collectionViewResizingTest.ViewController: 0x7ffbf9411ad0>>.
2020-07-02 16:34:06.922642+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-07-02 16:34:08.131628+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-07-02 16:34:08.131766+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2020-07-02 16:34:08.131940+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ffbfc016350>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7ffbf9844600; frame = (0 107.5; 414 788.5); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000017c9200>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000019d2ba0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1656, 768}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7ffbfc016350>; dataSource: <collectionViewResizingTest.ViewController: 0x7ffbf9411ad0>>.
2020-07-02 16:34:08.132058+1000 collectionViewResizingTest[97611:1371485] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I think it has something to do with the safe area at the bottom (this happens on devices in the simulator that have FaceID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting the `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`